# How i could find how program existing board with atmega chip on it

Tags: atmega

I have few "lego" roborobo sets (http://www.roboroboglobal.com/products/robokids1.html)
I'd like to find way to upload programs there written on PC.

On unit have ATMEGA16L chip and 6 pinholes with markings (Gnd, J3, VCC).

Another - ATMEGA64L, and RJ11 (marked J3) for programming.

J3 probably means one of the external connections types, as there are more J connectors (RJ11).

There is also kind of programmer, that also have RJ11 socket, and used to program 2nd unit with barcode cards. It have ATMEGA8L chip on it.

What software/hardware/components do i need to write and upload program there?

I wonder if I could make something that could be used by kids to learn programming. Set have buttons, leds, motors, but without possibility to upload programs, it would be nearly impossible to utilize it.

I'm very new to electronics, and only know how write simple things for arduino.

Comment: did you check the site for instruction and may be simple IDE on how to program them? http://www.roboroboglobal.com/support/download.html you cal always use dedicated JTAG SWD programmer but the site looks as if it supports other easy ways

Comment: IDE based on building blocks, I'm looking for possibility to write code. Also roboKIDS, that i have  (different from roboKIT, that this program is designed for) doesn't have any PC connectivity cable.

Comment: Out of interest. Why not arduino as platform to teach programming for kids..unless drivers are being developed.

Comment: Yes, we are using arduino for e.g. 12 years old. But for younger kids electronics is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How could I find out how to program an existing board with an ATmega chip on it?**

It is likely that the toy maker has provided a proprietary system for programming the toy. Reverse engineering that is out of scope here (at least it isn't something I'd spend much time attempting). However you can probably adopt a more generic approach as follows:

1. Look up the data sheet for the CPU chip

   - [ATMEGA16L](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2466.pdf)
2. Learn about the programming interface for that chip
3. Locate the appropriate programming pins on the IC and how to connect
   to them - look for programming pads (used with pogo pins) or headers
   (usually 3x2 or 5x2 0.1" header block for Atmel)
4. Work out how that chip has been wired up to the devices you want to use it with
5. Ensure there is no usage clash with pins needed for programming - or work out how to isolate those pins from other devices
6. Download a suitable program development environment

   - WinAVR and AVRdude
   - [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/software) (if your chip is supported and circuit is compatible)
   - [Atmel studio](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel-studio/)
   - etc
7. Obtain a suitable programmer

   - AVRISP
   - USBASP
   - [Pocket AVR Programmer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825)
   - [Arduino as In-System-Programmer (ISP)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP)
   - etc
8. Connect the programmer, easy if there is a programming header, 
   harder if you have to solder wires to pads or carefully to IC (especially hard for smaller SMD IC packages)
9. Learn the appropriate programming language
10. Use the IDE to develop a small test program and upload it to the CPU.

Note that doing this will likely overwrite any bootloader the maker programmed into the CPU and may therefore render it unusable with the original toolset provided by the toy maker.

---

References

- [LadyAda - AVR Tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/index.html)
- [Atmel - Getting Started](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/start_now.aspx)
- [LadyAda - Choosing a programmer](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/programmers.html) (a bit old)
- [Hackaday - AVR Programming intro](http://hackaday.com/2010/10/23/avr-programming-introduction/)